# Exhaust Fan Runs With No Power at All!

Tags: furnace, exhaust-fan, exhaust

How can my furnace exhaust fan run with the power off, the thermostat off, and the breaker off?!

Comment: If it's running under power, check your breakers again. If it's turning slowly, wind might be blowing in your exhaust vents. Check those two things.

Comment: It can't. You're mistaken. Is there a local power switch near the furnace?

Comment: Shut off (nicely) anything (like a desktop computer) that would mind and turn the MAIN breaker off. Still running, or no?

Comment: What kind of furnace is this? (Make/model would be helpful)

Answer (score 3):

### Some furnaces have more than one breaker

Well, *most* honestly.

- The Air Conditioning unit has a breaker
- If present, electric heating elements (e.g. emergency heat) have one or more breakers
- The blower will have its own breaker, typically shared with the electronics on a gas furnace
- A built-in humidifier or dehumidifer may have its own breaker
- Depending on location, the 24V thermostat transformer may be on yet another breaker

Unrelated, the radon venting system has its own breaker.